Why crystal wave number $k$ is the constant of motion?
I thought if there is an operator $\hat A$ which commutes with Hamiltonian $\hat H$, the eigenvalue of the corresponding observable $A$ should be the constant of motion.
In free space $(V=0)$, $$[\hat H, \hat p]=0,\quad \hat p|p\rangle=\mathbf p|p\rangle$$
so we can find that the eigenvalue $\mathbf p$ is the constant of the motion, which is momentum.
In case of crystal, $\hat p$ does not commute with Hamiltonian, but the translation operator with lattice vector $\mathbf R$ commutes with Hamiltonian.
$$[\hat H, \hat T(\mathbf R)]=0$$
Also by Bloch's Theorem, there exists quantum number $\mathbf k$ (which looks so similiar with the wave number $\mathbf k$) that satisfies
$$\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r+\mathbf R)=e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf R}\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r)$$
So I guessed:
$$\hat H\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r)=E\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r), \quad \hat T(\mathbf R)\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r)=\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r+\mathbf R)=e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf R}\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r)$$
then $\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r)$ would be the common eigenstate for both of them, and the eigenvalues would be $E$ and $e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf R}$.
But I couldn't come up with the observable concept for the translation operator $\hat T$, so I cannot understand why we could use $\mathbf k$ for the constant of motion even if $\mathbf p$ is not.
Does my statement above shows that the steady state solutions are identified with only $\mathbf k$? If so, I think I'm not familiar with the concept of $\mathbf k$. How can I understand $\mathbf k$ intuitively? And how could it be preserved?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_momentum

k here does not take on continuous values as momentum does. It is by no means a solution to the quantum mechanical momentum operator. Here it can take on certain descrete values which come from the following equation
Born-Von Karman boundary condition
$$\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r+\mathbf L_i)=\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r)  i= 1,2,3$$ $i= 1,2,3$ corresponds to the directions of primitive traslation vectors, $\mathbf L_i$ are the crystal dimensions.
Also we require
$$\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r+\mathbf L_i)=e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf L_i}\psi_\mathbf k(\mathbf r)$$
The above two equations require
$e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf L_i}=1$.
Here
$\mathbf L_i=N_i \mathbf a_i$
$\mathbf a_i$ are the primitive translation vectors and $N_i$ are large numbers.
The requirement is satisfied provided
$ \mathbf k= \sum_{i=1}^{3}s_i \mathbf b_i/N_i$
$\mathbf b_i$ are receprocal lattice vectors
$s_i$ takes 0 and interger values.
So $ \mathbf k$ is nothing more than a quantum number labelled by $s_i$.
This is a note regarding momentum conservation.
The transformation that performs the translation is given by
T(R)=exp(-iR.P/$\hbar$)
That is the hamiltomian H after transformation is H`. Basically the equation goes as
H`=exp(-iR.P/$\hbar$) H exp(iR.P/$\hbar$). However there is a relation
exp(A)Bexp(-A)=B + [A,B]+[A,[A,B]]/2+....
Applying to the translation
H`=H + -iR.[P,H]...
Since H is invariant under translation H`=H. Which makes P commute with H and thus a constant of motion. In this case R is restricted and cannot have any value. P is not constant over all space.

But crystal momentum (which is hbark) does represent the detivative of external force / also multiplication of (effective) mass and (group) velocity. I understand p could not be determined with E at the same time, but then why m × v_g would be crystal momentum?

@Modern your questions are typically explicitly answered in a good textbook on crystalline physics, and if you want to go into the details, you would have to compute the commutators of the relevant operators with the Hamiltonian operator yourself. .

Sure you do call $\hbar k$ crystal momentum because it enters in conservation laws realted to lattice collisions. It would be momentum as we know what momentum is provided the potential term is zero as in the Sommerfeld model, which imposes perodicity on the wave function with no potential term. The question is why should it not be a constant, quantum numbers are specefic to a quantum mechanical state. If collision occurs then k would change but take on one of the quantum numbers mentioned.

Dont know what you mean when you say observational concept of translational operator. T (R) is an operator that translates the coordinates of the wave function by an amount R. This has implications as is apparent. Just as we have operators that perform rotations.

Just a word to add the generator of translation is linear momentum.

KRONIG-PENNEY MODEL gives a good connection between $E=(hK)^2$/2m and the k used as a quantum number. External forces have an effect on k.
